# Is it possible to configure ssh during u-boot?

Tags: kernel, driver, bootloader, u-boot

Usually u-boot can be accessed with a serial communication such as UART.

I am using raspberry pi 3 b+, and I need to access u-boot with ssh through an Ethernet cable.

Is is it possible to configure ssh during u-boot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH is running on top of TCP but U-Boot only supports UDP.

You can use the U-Boot netconsole. But that traffic will not be encrypted.

https://github.com/trini/u-boot/blob/master/doc/README.NetConsole

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Working link to the U-Boot NetConsole documentation: https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/doc/usage/netconsole.rst